# Компонент WebBrowser: отобразить часть сайта

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Добрый день.

Необходимо отобразить часть сайта при помощи компонента `WebBrowser`, не вывести `html` код (средствами `WebBrowser.DocumentText`), а именно отобразить, и отобразить строго (только несколько полей из формы которые идут подряд).

Спасибо.

Уточнение на примере авито.

Имеем:

1. http://m.avito.ru/add
2. `JavaScript` отключен

Необходимо:
В компонент `WebBrowser` вывести все подкатегории "Категория", скрин:

[image: img]

т.е. отобразить в `WebBrowser` полный функционал "Категория" со всеми его подкаталогами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как запихать `html` уже ответили.
Вот описание хорошей `.net`-библиотеки для парсинга.
[Html Agility Pack — удобный .NET парсер HTML](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112325/)

**UPD**

Парсишь при помощи HTML Agility Pack `<select name="category_id" id="category_id">`, вытаскиваешь id и содержимое каждого option. Содержимое - для отображения.

[image: img]

Дальше идёшь в дев-консоль браузера и смотришь куда уходят запросы.

[image: img2]

Переходишь по [этому](http://m.avito.ru/request/paramsForAdd_9) адресу и получаешь кучу `JSONа`.

`JSON` в более читаемый вид можешь переформировать [здесь](http://jsonformat.com/).

Всё, радуйся жизни, читай JSON, парсь его и верти как душе угодно.

Comment: большой плюс к HTML Agility Pack, одна из лучших библиотек для парсинга под .NET

Answer (score 2):

Получите html код страницы, распарсите его и выведите в браузере:

```
var browser = CreateBrowser(size); 
browser.Navigate("about:blank"); 
browser.Document.Write(html);
```